# Google Custom Search - error jsapi

Tags: google-custom-search

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("search", "1");
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1></h1>
    <div>
        <script>
          (function() {
            var cx = 'SECRET';
            var gcse = document.createElement('script');
            gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
            gcse.async = true;
            gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
          })();
        </script>
        <gcse:search></gcse:search>
    </div>
</body>
```

GET https://www.google.com/uds/?file=ads&v=3&packages=search&async=2 jsapi:21 google.(anonymous function).djsapi:27 (anonymous function)jsapi:18 (anonymous function)jsapi?autoload={"modules"%3A[{"name"%3A"search"%2C"version"%3A"1.0"%2C"callback"%3A"__gcse.scb"%2C"…:41 (anonymous function)

I have my code above.  I'm getting the following error in my console.  I'm getting search results which is good, but the error is creating other problems on my site.  Do you know what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: i do not think it's a bug. I think it is because it is going to relevant paths and not http within the code. Use a console and check the errors. Chrome or Firefox :  Inspect element > Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a google bug, see discussion in their product forum [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/customsearch/9WJ2G1rJXWE/eoVd-_FarBsJ)

Comment: Link above is out of date.

Comment: Whilst this might answer the question, I hate it when I see link only answers. How about putting in some explanation here? Just copy pasting the answer that you think is right would have helped...